# Removing emojis that start with '\x' in pandas/Python when reading a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

How can I remove emojis that start with '\x' when reading a csv file using pandas in Python? The CSV file has lots of emojis in the text and I want to remove them. However, the normal pattern matching regex for emojis doesn't work on it. Here is an example:

```
Thx WP for performing key democratic function. Trump wants to live in post truth world where words don't matter.  D\xe2\x80\xa6 |\xef\xbf\xa3\xef\xbf\xa3\xef\xbf\xa3\xef\xbf\xa3\xef\xbf\xa3\xef\xbf\xa3\xef\xbf\xa3\xef\xbf\xa3\xef\xbf\xa3\xef\xbf\xa3|\n        ME LA PELAS \n      DONALD TRUMP \n|\xef\xbc\xbf\xef\xbc\xbf\xef\xbc\xbf\xef\xbc\xbf\xef\xbc\xbf\xef\xbc\xbf\xef\xbc\xbf\xef\xbc\xbf\xef\xbc\xbf\xef\xbc\xbf|  \n             (\\__/)   ||\n             (\xe2\x80\xa2\xe3\x85\x85\xe2\x80\xa2) ||\n            / \xe3\x80\x80 \xe3\x81\xa5
```

Here is an example of the code that works on normal emojis but not these ones:

```
import re 

text = u'This dog \xe2\x80\x9d \xe2\x80\x9c' 
print(text) # with emoji 

emoji_pattern = re.compile("[" 
        u"\U0001F600-\U0001F64F"  # emoticons 
        u"\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF"  # symbols & pictographs 
        u"\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF"  # transport & map symbols 
        u"\U0001F1E0-\U0001F1FF"  # flags (iOS) 
                           "]+", flags=re.UNICODE) 
print(emoji_pattern.sub(r'', text)) # no emoji
```

So, the following piece of code works:

```
import unicodedata 
from unidecode import unidecode 

def deEmojify(inputString): 
    returnString = "" 
    for character in inputString: 
        try: 
            character.encode("ascii") 
            returnString += character 
        except UnicodeEncodeError: 
            returnString += '' 
    return returnString 


print(deEmojify("I'm loving all the trump hate on Twitter right now \xf0\x9f\x99\x8c"))
```

But when I am reading from a csv using pandas it doesn't work and emojis are not removed:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv("Trump834.csv", encoding="utf-8") 


import unicodedata   
from unidecode import unidecode   

def deEmojify(inputString):   
    returnString = ""   
    for character in inputString:   
        try:   
            character.encode("ascii")   
            returnString += character   
        except UnicodeEncodeError:   
            returnString += ''   
    return returnString   



for i in range(df.shape[0]): 
    print(df.iloc[i]['Tweet']) 
    print(deEmojify(df.iloc[i]['Tweet'])) 
    print("****************************************")
```

Comment: Where / how is this csv-file being generated? It looks like there has been some encoding/decoding issues.

Comment: please see the last part of the updated question. I was given the files so Idk! @juanpa.arrivillaga

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is your source files were decoded incorrectly.  Re-encode them with the incorrect encoding (probably `cp1252` or `latin`) and decode them correctly as `utf8`.

For example:

```
>>> s = u'This dog \xe2\x80\x9d \xe2\x80\x9c'
>>> s.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
'This dog ” “'
>>> s = u'''Thx WP for performing key democratic function. Trump wants to live in post truth world where words don't matter.  D\xe2\x80\xa6 |\xef\xbf\xa3\xef\xbf\xa3\xef\xbf\xa3\xef\xbf\xa3\xef\xbf\xa3\xef\xbf\xa3\xef\xbf\xa3\xef\xbf\xa3\xef\xbf\xa3\xef\xbf\xa3|\n        ME LA PELAS \n      DONALD TRUMP \n|\xef\xbc\xbf\xef\xbc\xbf\xef\xbc\xbf\xef\xbc\xbf\xef\xbc\xbf\xef\xbc\xbf\xef\xbc\xbf\xef\xbc\xbf\xef\xbc\xbf\xef\xbc\xbf|  \n             (\\__/)   ||\n             (\xe2\x80\xa2\xe3\x85\x85\xe2\x80\xa2) ||\n            / \xe3\x80\x80 \xe3\x81\xa5'''
>>> print(s.encode('latin1').decode('utf8'))
Thx WP for performing key democratic function. Trump wants to live in post truth world where words don't matter.  D… |￣￣￣￣￣￣￣￣￣￣|
        ME LA PELAS
      DONALD TRUMP
|＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿|
             (\__/)   ||
             (•ㅅ•) ||
            / 　 づ
>>> s="I'm loving all the trump hate on Twitter right now \xf0\x9f\x99\x8c"
>>> s.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
"I'm loving all the trump hate on Twitter right now "
```

Then your emoji-removal should work.